# Mostrar que un botón fue presionado al presionar una tecla

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy tratando de mostrar que el botón se muestre presionado como cuando lo presionas con el click izquierdo del mouse pero haciéndolo con una tecla del teclado, como por ejemplo: la calculadora de Windows cuando se presiona el Numpad1 el botón 1 de la calculadora se presiona.
Esto es lo que llevo.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad1)
    {
        //Hacer que el botón se muestre presionado
        button1.PerformClick(); //Se presiona el botón pero no muestra la animación
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Pedro, si la respuesta te resulto util podrias marcarla como aceptada, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes ir a tu formulario y poner su **propiedad KeyPreview** en **true**. Por otra parte de la forma que lo estás haciendo solamente se ejecutarán las teclas numéricas que están a la derecha de tu teclado, sin embargo las teclas numéricas que están en la parte superior de tu teclado no se ejecutarán, para lograr que ambas teclas de números puedan ejecutarse te recomiendo que en vez de usar el **evento KeyDown** uses el **evento KeyPress** de tu formulario con este código:

```
if(e.KeyChar == '1')
{
   button1.PerformClick();
}
```

De esta forma cada vez que se presione el número **1**, se ejecutará tu código.